# What are *.tflite model output

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

This is my code of a tensorflow Lite model imported on Android Studio :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDPVo.png)

And this is the out put When I run the App:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCe4n.jpg)

I Don't understand it , How can I get the model  Output ??

update :

The output is Float Array of 6 elements , but what I want is the Index of the Largesse element , I tried this code :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oDAy.png)

Is It right ??  I'm getting the same output `1-` on every  prediction

Comment: floatArray is your output

Comment: But what I want is the Index of the Largesse element of it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your TFLite model generates a feature vector as a float array, which represents the characteristics of the image data.

See also https://brilliant.org/wiki/feature-vector/

The feature vector is usually considered as an intermediate data and it often requires to put the feature vectors again to the additional model for image classifications or some other tasks.

Comment: Can I convert this feature vector to this array  `float32[1,6]`  that is supposed to be the output ??

Comment: Looks like the outputFeature0 is the output of your model. However, due to the lack of information of your TFLite model, I am not sure what it is.  It can contains the image classification result or the feature vector I mentioned in the above comment.